# Azure WebJobs cannot connect to mdf database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-webjobs, mdf

I am developing an Azure website and a WebJob.  The development database is an Mdf file.  The Mvc app can connect to Azure storage and the database.  The WebJob can connect to the Azure storage, but the database throws this:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Specified LocalDB instance name is invalid.
)
  Source=Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
```

Both the Mvc and WebJob share the same connection strings:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Projects\\Test1\\Code\\Database\\Test1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False
```

It doesn't make any difference if the Mvc app is running when the WebJob is started.

Answer (score 0):

In the MVC app user secrets, I had to use double slashes, like this:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB
```

In the app.config file for the webjob console app, I had to use single slashes like this:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB
```